# DLE, как вставить статичный блок по центру страницы?

Tags: html, css, gulp, dle

Вставляя его через bb-код мы теряем кнопку и input, как можно вставить его статичным объектом именно по центру страницы, не в шапке и в футере?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не забудьте добавить в форму согласие на обработку персональных данных

Answer (score 0):

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Comment: Оффтоп, читайте внимательнее.